# Maximum range error on click event in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a reproducable error here, where I run into a `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

It's just a click event I call onto a link.

My HTML:

```
<div id="box">
    <a href="#">test</a>
</div>
```

My Javascript:

```
$('#box').click(function() {
    ("a", $(this)).click();
});
```

Now, clicking the `#box` leads to an error.

http://jsfiddle.net/DMAMv/2/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should stop the propagation with [stopImmediatePropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/)(), otherwise you have too much rcursion

```
$('#box').click(function() {
    $("a:first", this).click();
});
$('a').click(function(e){
   e.stopImmediatePropagation();
   alert('hi');
});
```

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DMAMv/8/

Comment: thank you so much for this...this was driving me insane :)

Answer (score 9):

That's because it is recursively triggering the click event. This is caused by two problems.

The first is this innocent looking line:

```
("a", $(this)).click();  # note the missing $ at the beginning
```

That essentially reduces to `$(this).click()` (because the [comma operator](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) evaluates both operands and returns the second one) and so your click event on `#container` triggers itself. Consider the following examples - http://jsfiddle.net/2VnbG/ and http://jsfiddle.net/2VnbG/1/ - notice how the parent div is targetted when the `$` is missing.

Prepend the line with the missing `$` to solve that issue, i.e. `$("a", $(this)).click();`

The next problem is that a click event on the anchor will bubble up to the parent object (in your case, `#container`). If the parent has a bound function on the click event which triggers a new event, then the cycle is going to repeat infinitely.

To solve that, use [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) to stop the event from bubbling up the DOM tree.

Here's an example with the above fixes in place: http://jsfiddle.net/DMAMv/9/

Answer (score 3):

mine was a list item in a dropdown so i wanted the event to keep bubbling so the dropdown would be closed. this is the solution i used:

```
$('div#outer').click(function (e) {
   if (e.target == e.currentTarget) // prevents bubbled events from triggering
      $($(e.currentTarget).children()[0]).trigger('click');
});
```